# Get currently pressed key in C?

Tags: c, linux

I need to be able to get the current character being pressed without stopping the program entirely. Ideally, I would like the program to continue running, checking for the key after every iteration of a while loop. `getch()` is problematic for this reason. I want to break out of a while loop when the 'q' key is pressed, but for the while loop to continue running until then. I am using Linux with gcc as my compiler.

Comment: take a look at http://shtrom.ssji.net/skb/getc.html

Comment: There was a similar post posted a week ago. Try `if(kbhit())getch();`. `kbhit()` will return 0 if no key is pressed.

Comment: @CoolGuy: But `kbhit` is not a standard Linux function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In practice, you should **use a library** and it depends if you are writing a terminal application or a GUI one.

For *terminal applications*, read the [TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page and **use [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or [readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/)**. Be aware that in cooked mode (which is the default case), a [tty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Text_terminals) has a kernel-managed line buffer, hence getting a single character thru `getc` is not possible. See also [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) and [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) and [tty_ioctl(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html) (you could take the pain the set the tty in raw mode -e.g. as in http://shtrom.ssji.net/skb/getc.html suggested in a comment by [sjr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373653/sjr)-, but I recommend using a library).

For *graphical applications* running on a desktop, **use some toolkit like [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io/)**.

BTW, in both cases the programming model is no more compatible with the naive `getc` function.

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and be aware that Linux has several multiplexing [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (these are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)), notably [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) -which is probably used by *ncurses* or *readline* or *Qt* or *Gtk* libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this! I decided to go with the termios library to change terminal settings. works well!

Comment: Don't forget to reset the terminal setting before exiting your program. But you really should use `ncurses` or `readline`. If your program terminates prematurely, your terminal is in bad state.

Comment: That is a concern. How could I do the same thing in NCurses?

Comment: Both `ncurses` and `readline` have very good documentation and examples.

Comment: Okay, I will look into that.