# Consecutive calls to scanf

Tags: c

I was helping a classmate with his code and had run across this.
I have had some issues with scanf in the past probably due to my lack of experience, but that is why I'm here.

So, I noticed that two consecutive calls to scanf or grabbing multiple input from one call can be problematic. Consider the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){

char input1, input2;

//In
fprintf(stdout,"\nInput1: ");
fscanf(stdin,"%d",&input1);
fprintf(stdout,"\nInput2: ");
fscanf(stdin, "%d", &input2);

//Out
fprintf(stdout,"\nInput1: %d Input2: %d\n",input1,input2);

}
```

Why is it that scanf will print to the screen the desired values of input1 & input2 yet when I print back those same two variables with printf, the second value (input2) seems to have overwritten Input1?

This is the output.

```
Input1: 1

Input2: 0

Input1: 0 Input2: 0
```

Does this have anything to do with the line buffer? If so, could someone explain this to me.

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lying both to `scanf()` and to `printf()` about the types of variables `input1` and `input2`.  The `%d` field descriptor promises that the corresponding argument is an `int` (or a pointer to one, for `scanf()`), but the actual type in your code is `char`.  The behavior of the resulting program is undefined.

Your program works fine for me if I change the variables' type to `int`.

Comment: Thanks man. You make a good point. I'm dealing with two things though 1's and 0's performing logic gates. I only need one byte storage.

Comment: Supposing that you have a bunch of these, so that one-byte vs. (probably) four-byte storage makes a real difference, you can scan into a temporary `int`, validate the result, and if it's ok then assign it to a separate `char` variable.  On output, all you need to do is cast to `int` if you want to use a `%d` field descriptor.

Comment: I see, good idea. It doesn't entirely matter, but I like to know all my options.

Answer (score 1):

change `char input1, input2;` to `int input1, input2;`

Comment: It works, but what if i want to treat it as a char? What would you suggest?

Comment: But be aware that if you use `%c` to scan a digit character such as '0', the *numeric* value of the resulting `char` is different from the value the digit *represents*.  That is, `'0' != 0`.

Comment: Yeah I ran across that earlier. Just looking for that 1 byte storage.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should (in general, notably for interactive programs) rather put `\n` at *end* not beginning of `printf` of `fprintf` format control string. Or else use `fflush`

BTW, `%d` is for `int`s so declare `int input1, input2;` and if enabling all warnings with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) e.g. compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` you would have been warned.

Then, you should *always* test the result of `scanf` (or `fscanf`); it gives the number of read items.

See [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html), [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html), [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html)

If on Linux, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29361728/841108) about not waiting for full lines.

Comment: Why not put `\n` at the beginning of a `printf()` format control string?  That's perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Because of buffering.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps it would be sensible to qualify your advice to make it clear that it applies specifically to printing interactive prompts.

Answer (score 0):

You used %d that reads an integer and store in a variable of type char, which is totally wrong.